# Where can I find good D3 event and dispatch examples?

Tags: javascript, events, d3.js, dispatch

I'm trying to find some easy to understand and use tutorials for D3 that specifically focus on how to implement and use Events and the Dispatch functions.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This appears to be a duplicate of your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9882226) on events and dispatch. Nearly every D3 example (at least the interactive ones) demonstrate using [selection.on](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#wiki-on) to respond to user interface events. See the [D3 wiki](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki) for an extensive list of examples and tutorials.

Comment: Thanks.  Got it all finally work.  If anyone is interested, I've created three D3 based examples that each use mouseover and mouseout events to synchronize behavior across multiple objects... 1) [Pie Charts](http://bl.ocks.org/2212156), 2) [Horizontal Bar Charts](http://bl.ocks.org/2141479), and 3) [Vertical Bar Charts](http://bl.ocks.org/2164562).  I hope others find them useful.