# How can I use d3 classed selection to have name as function

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am using [d3 classed selections](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection#selection_classed) and in first parameter, instead of a string, I want to use a function that will returns class name.

```
selection.classed(name[, value])
```

I understand I can do the same using `.attr()` as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11420568/d3-js-tree-layout-how-to-name-classes-using-a-function), but I want to be able to do the same using classed.

How can I do this?

Comment: Don't know if it was available when this question was asked (d3 v.3), but in more recent versions there's `selection.each()` that can be used to that effect. One of the more recent answers shows how. I think it's more relevant to what's asked here than the accepted answer.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

The class name you provide there needs to be fixed, i.e. you cannot have something like `function(d) { return d; }`. If you need the class name to be determined by the data, you need to use `.attr("class", ...)`.

If you're worried about overwriting existing class names, note that you can retrieve and prepend those as follows.

```
.attr("class", function(d) { return d3.select(this).attr("class") + " " + d; })
```

Comment: This is exactly what I doing currently, I am pretending the class names. I was just wondering if there is any direct way to do it. Thanks for your response.

Comment: For the record, here is a relevant pull request to implement this using classed, and the reason it was rejected - https://github.com/mbostock/d3/pull/1072

Comment: If you want to do this using an arrow function to keep `this` pointing to whatever it is outside the function you can do it like `.attr('class', (d, i, nodes) => d3.select(nodes[i]).attr('class') + ' ' + this.someMethod(d) )`

Comment: If you prefer `classed(class, true)` over `attr('class', ...)`, you can do `selection.each(function(d) {d3.select(this).classed(d.class, true)})`

Answer (score 5):

I encountered a similar problem in which I wanted to add one class if a property on my datum was true and a different class if the property was false:

```
selection.classed('class-one', function(d) { return d.property; })
    .classed('class-two', function(d) { return d.property; });
```

If you have a small number of classes to add then something like this might be worth considering.

Answer (score 4):

Similar to the suggested answer, but I found

```
selection.each(function(d) { d3.select(this).classed(d.class, true)
```

also works.

Answer (score 2):

Lars answer is great, but if you start out with no class on the attribute it will add the class 'null' to the element as the null attribute is forced to a string. Natural next step from his:

```
.attr("class", function(d) {
      var existing = d3.select(this).attr("class") 
      if (existing == null){
        return d.column.class
      }else{
        return existing + " " + d.column.class
      }
})
```

This could be made into a one-liner with a ternary operator if you want it more concise