# Selections in D3, Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js

In the answer Mike posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9882226/how-to-properly-add-and-use-d3-events), he overviews three different ways to apply a change to a matched element based on a index or custom filter. I'm trying to clarify, hopefully for more people than just myself, the actual selections in these solutions.

So given a document with 6 SVG rects with class `.bar`, we have these different selections and what they return:

**d3.select(".bar"):**

```
[Array[1]  
0: rect.[object SVGAnimatedString]  
length: 1  
parentNode: html  
__proto__: Array[0]
```

**d3.selectAll(".bar"):**

```
[Array[6]  
0: rect.[object SVGAnimatedString]  
1: rect.[object SVGAnimatedString]  
2: rect.[object SVGAnimatedString]  
3: rect.[object SVGAnimatedString]  
4: rect.[object SVGAnimatedString]  
5: rect.[object SVGAnimatedString]  
length: 6  
parentNode: html  
__proto__: Array[0]
```

**$(".bar"):**

```
[
<rect class=​"dataBars" x=​"53.191489361702125" width=​"212.7659574468085" y="4.761904761904762" height=​"11.11111111111111">​</rect>​,  
<rect class=​"dataBars" x=​"74.46808510638297" width=​"372.3404255319149" y=​"20.634920634920636" height=​"11.11111111111111">​</rect>​, 
<rect class=​"dataBars" x=​"127.6595744680851" width=​"212.7659574468085" y=​"36.507936507936506" height=​"11.11111111111111">​</rect>,​  
<rect class=​"dataBars" x=​"31.914893617021274" width=​"212.7659574468085" y=​"52.38095238095238" height=​"11.11111111111111">​</rect>​,  
<rect class=​"dataBars" x=​"159.5744680851064" width=​"265.9574468085106" y=​"68.25396825396825" height=​"11.11111111111111">​</rect>​,  
<rect class=​"dataBars" x=​"234.04255319148936" width=​"138.29787234042553" y=​"84.12698412698413" height=​"11.11111111111111">​</rect>​,
]
```

Now here's where it get's more tricky (for me at least), say I want to apply a `style` to the 3rd rectangle, this rectangle can be found using

```
d3.selectAll(".bar")[0][2]
```

But if we want to then use the `d3.selection.attr()`, that returns

```
TypeError: Property 'style' of object #<SVGRectElement> is not a function
```

But we can then wrap this selection

```
d3.select(d3.selectAll(".bars rect")[0][2]).style("fill", "red")
```

and this will work as expected.

Then, if we want to apply a filter, such as

```
filter(function (d) { return d === 5 || d === 15;}
```

the `d3.selectAll(".bar")` must be used, and `d3.select(d3.selectAll(".bar"))` will not work correctly.

I've read Mike's excellent tutorials and documentation on selections, but just when I think I have it figured out, something pops up and surprises me. So what is the difference between these selections, and how do I know which one to use when? Thank you very much, and sorry for the long post!

Comment: Well, `d3.selectAll(".bar")[0][2]` returns the "raw" DOM element and DOM elements don't have a `style` function. `d3.select(d3.selectAll(".bar"))` does not work because `.select` expects either a DOM element or a selector (string), but not a D3 selection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, you shouldn't access elements of a returned selection by their indices, but rather filter or use a subselection. This way, you can apply `.attr()` and `.atyle()` without problems. The reason for this is that D3 doesn't return a "pure" array of DOM elements (like jquery does), but the elements in a wrapper that supports the D3 operations. It still behaves somewhat like an array though -- if you index into it, you get a "pure" DOM element. You can also give a DOM element to `d3.select()` and it will generate the wrapper around this element that enables all the D3 stuff.

If you have a look at the [documentation for `filter()`](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#wiki-filter), you'll find some examples on how to use it and subselections. You can use these techniques to get the third element of a selection for example. Using the `.filter()` function only makes sense if you have bound data to the objects you're filtering, otherwise a subselection should do what you want.

Comment: jQuery doesn't return an array of elements either. It returns a jQuery object which is *array-like* and lets you access the selected elements via their index.

Comment: What's the difference to a normal array? The return value looks like a plain array to me.

Comment: Only because the Chrome console displays array-like objects like normal arrays. It's true that jQuery objects resemble arrays pretty well (they even have `.push` and `.splice` methods, but no `.pop`). But they also have many more methods (`.filter`, `.find`, `.on`, ...), that arrays don't have, i.e. you have the same as with D3: A wrapper that provides all the jQuery functionality. And if that is still not convincing, `$('.bar') instanceof Array` returns `false`.

Answer (score 5):

I've tried to do this in the past and run into similar errors.  Then I realized that I was not really following the intended API.  The second that you start accessing selection elements by index, you're way off the beaten path.

See [nested selections](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/nest/)

So, if you wanted to style your third bar, you would do

```
d3.selectAll(".bar").style("color", function(d,i) { return i === 2 ? "red" : null; } )
```

And if your selection is one level more nested than that, make it `function(d,i,j)` and similarly go from there.  Etc.

Comment: Like Lars suggests, you can also the selection before updating the style to avoid setting anything to null: d3.selectAll(".bar rect").filter(function(d, i){ return i == 2; }).style("fill", "red")

Comment: @roippi thanks for the example on the filters, would upvote but I have no reputation!