# how to display the node attributes like person's name photo and address in a force directed graph

Tags: javascript, d3.js, force-layout

Hi I am working on a force directed graph example of d3.js library   but i want to fix the positions of all nodes. And When i click on the node I want to display a pop up which shows  image and some info of user(node).

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to do my best to answer, but there is a lot to cover in your question, so this is more of an overview of where to look for more info, and a bit to get you started down the right path.

Please excuse the shoddy links ( I can't post more than two yet...)

Nodes can be fixed position by setting the boolean "fixed" property of each individual node to true.

See Sections on: # force.nodes([nodes])
https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Force-Layout

To make nodes clickable, you could attach an event listener to the node selection as you are appending new nodes to the node selection.
See here: Github /mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#wiki-on

To add more properties to each node, simply add that data to your objects inside the "node" array before joining it to your selection.

Here is a edit to it that I made to show how you can add a drag behavior, and a mouse "click" listener event to toggle nodes between fixed=true and false, with some comments on where you would add additional node properties, and possibly make function calls to display more node info.
https://gist.github.com/alexhornbake/6079321

The above was edited from the following example. I still refer back to this example when I get confused, very helpful/simple Force Layout Example:
Gist GitHub /mbostock/1095795

Answer (score 0):

To add to Alex's answer, here's a simple example, assuming you've associated a property `name` with each data value. So you'll want to have a `g` element for every node, and each `g` would have both a `circle` and a `text`. You can then relate the two through indices or values as Mike Bostock explains [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9882226/how-to-properly-add-and-use-d3-events). Note the data is automatically inherited from the parent. Use the associated on click event to add or remove a class to the text that will show or hide it. This can be done using `selection.classed()`

```
var nodes = d3.select("body").append("svg:g")
                     .selectAll("g.nodeGroup")
                     .data(dataset)
                     .enter()
                     .attr("class", "nodeGroup")
                     .attr("x", function(d) { ...
                          ...
                     .each(function(d) { 
                            d3.select(this).append("circle")
                                    .attr("r", function(p) { return p.value})
                                    .on("click", function(p) {
                                         d3.selectAll("g.nodeGroup text")
                                            .filter(q) { return p.value == q.value}
                                            .classed("show", true)});
                            d3.select(this).append("text")
                                     .attr("text", function (P) { return p.name})
                   });
```

Comment: can you please let me know how do i replace the circle to a square and i want to show image on clicking the node please share any example code please let me know how do i add image to each node if  i have a url in my json input data